# Blender Game Engine: Added objects from actuater are invisible.

Tags: game-engine

I was adding an object with multiple child objects from a different layer. It was working fine in testing, but then I tested it again after making changes and all the objects appeared invisible. This is the same for any added object whether it has child objects or not. I have been unable to get the added objects visible again. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: what changes were made? we need more information to solve the problem.

Comment: move all your child objects onto the same layer as your main object that is being added. When objects are parented across different layers, unless all layers are visible, the child objects will be invisible.

Comment: I added an object that would act like a coin, it was given a yellow material and would disappear when it collided with any object with the variable "player", but after deleting this object it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, somehow every object wanted to add had "Invisible" turned on. I never did this, and I don't know how it was done either.